# PHP: Sending special characters in links?

Tags: php, get, character

With this link:

```
<a href="test.php?id=John & doe">Test</a>
```

On test.php I try to retrieve the variable but it only outputs John.

How to get the whole name John & Doe?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.php.net/urlencode

What you have now is basically id = John and doe=. Because & separates parameters, you need to encode it to use the literal ampersand. The spaces also need to be encoded.

Comment: Yes I was also looking at that but the referring site is not a php page (it's program calling a php page). I fixed it by sending John XXX Doe and then performing a str_replace before submitting it to a database. Not pretty but it works. Thank you ^^

Answer (score 1):

You must [percent encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the spaces and ampersands:

```
<a href="test.php?id=John%20%26%20doe">Test</a>
```

A space must be escaped to `%20` in a URL, and since the `&` separates parameters in the part of the URL after `?`, you must escape that also (to `%26`).